# Magento 2 Get Ordered Products Where Order Status Is X

Tags: magento, magento2, product, items

I'm new to Magento 2 and I'm building a module.

I would like Magento to produce a list of all items that have been ordered, filtered by `order_status`.

Example:

```
SELECT [product] FROM sale_order_product WHERE order_status = 'pending'
```

How would this be done with models/resource models/collections/repositories?

Answer (score 3):

You can get the items details from order by using the below code. You can add a status filter on order collection according to your needs.

```
$objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
     $orderDatamodel = $objectManager->get('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->getCollection();
     foreach($orderDatamodel as $orderDatamodel1){
     $getid =  $orderDatamodel1->getData("increment_id");
         $orderData = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->loadByIncrementId($getid);
          //echo "<pre>";
          $getorderdata = $orderData->getData();
          $orderItems = $orderData->getAllVisibleItems();
          foreach($orderItems as $orderItems){
                    print_r($orderItems->getData());
        }
     }
```

Comment: Please make sure to add to your answer that it is always bad to use the object manager directly and that DI should be used instead.